# How to get nano to work properly under mutt?

Tags: unix, mutt, nano

I have set nano as the default editor in mutt; mutt launches nano normally enough, but when I try to send the message (ie. save and quit, separately) mutt says the message has been aborted. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `.muttrc`:

```
set editor="nano -t +8"
```

Comment: What purposes are served by `-t` and `+8`? (Mutt is new to me …)